Iterm2 disable highlighting of individual parts in terminal
After the update, a problem appeared. I can click on any part of the console, and it highlights that place and makes the rest of the place lighter. How to turn it off?

The feature is called "Selection" which can be turned off via the Settings/General/Selection menu.


I might specifically point out that it is the "Clicking on a command selects it to restrict Find and Filter" option.
